# Writing .wav file from byte array in java

Tags: java, wav, javax.sound.sampled

I need to read a `.WAV` file, apply some sort offset of semitones, and rewrite it to a new `.WAV` file.

I figured out how to convert the file to a byte array, but I'm not sure how to rewrite this to a new `.WAV` file. I am using the `javax.sound.sampled.*` library.

I know that there is a function `AudioSystem.write(AudioInputStream, FileFormat, File)`, but I just don't know how to create the `AudioInputStream` from the byte array. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bais);
```

But make sure your byte array does contain the WAV header information. Otherwise you will probably get something like `could not get audio input stream from input stream`.